# flash.display.Loader intermitently causing children of loaded swf to loose type

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, loader

I have a class which loads two swfs using two loaders similar to this one (note new ApplicationDomain):

```
var child1Loader:Loader = new Loader()
child1Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild1Complete)
child1Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child1Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))
```

The loaded swfs are in fact factories:

```
public class Child1Factory extends Sprite
{

    public function Child1Factory() {}

    public function getChild1():Child1 {
        return new Child1()
    }

}
```

Once both swfs are loaded I add child1 and child2 to the stage like so:

```
var child1:MovieClip = child1Factory.getChild1()
var child2:MovieClip = child2Factory.getChild2()
addChild(child1)
addChild(child2)
```

Child1 and child2 look very similar but are not identical. Child1 looks like this (note ADDED_TO_STAGE listener):

```
public class Child1 extends MovieClip 
{

    public function Child1() 
    {
        Security.allowDomain("*")
        if (stage) onAddedToStage(null)
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage)         
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage)
        addChild(new MC_CircleGroup())
        runChild1Test()
    }

    private function runChild1Test():void {
        var circles:Array = findChildrenOfType(MC_Circle, this)
        if (circles.length == 0) {
            throw new Error("Oh no!")
        }
    }

    private function findChildrenOfType(type:Class, container:DisplayObjectContainer):Array {
        var toReturn:Array = []
        for (var childIndex:int = 0; childIndex < container.numChildren; childIndex++) {
            var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(childIndex)
            if (child is type) {
                toReturn.push(child)
            } else if (child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
                toReturn = toReturn.concat(findChildrenOfType(type, child as DisplayObjectContainer))
            }
        }
        return toReturn
    }

}
```

And child2 is similar except read square for circle. Both classes have different swcs containing the relevant MC_SquareGroup or MC_CircleGroup movieclips. These have four children in them of type MC_Square or MC_Circle. The findChildrenOfType function normally returns an array of these four instances.

The error "On no!" is thrown about 1 time in every 5 that I run the application. Does anyone now why? Or better still does anyone now of a workaround?

**Some notes:**

1.) The error is only thrown when I load the swfs over the internet or over a local network. It not thrown if the swfs are on the same computer.

2.) Loading child1 but not child2 or visa virsa works without any errors.

3.) When the error occurs, according to my debugger, the children of MC_CircleGroup are of type MovieClip, not MC_Circle.

4.) The error is not thrown every time I run the application. It only every few times. In order to get the error consistantly I have to loop the load by calling the loaders again once both swfs are loaded.

**Full source code available on request.**

Thanks!
Tim

**UPDATE**

The full code in the loader file looks like this:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var child1Factory:Object;
    private var child1Loaded:Boolean = false;
    private var child2Factory:Object;
    private var child2Loaded:Boolean = false;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        Security.allowDomain("*")
        if (stage) loadChildren();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);
    }

    private function loadChildren(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);

        child1Loaded = false
        child2Loaded = false

        var child1Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child1Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild1Complete)
        child1Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child1Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))

        var child2Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child2Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild2Complete)
        child2Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child2Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))


    }

    private function onChild1Complete(e:Event):void {
        child1Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child1Loaded = true
        if (child2Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }   

    }

    private function onChild2Complete(e:Event):void {
        child2Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child2Loaded = true
        if (child1Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }   

    }

    private function onLoadComplete():void {
        var child1:MovieClip = child1Factory.getChild1()
        var child2:MovieClip = child2Factory.getChild2()
        addChild(child1)
        addChild(child2)
        loadChildren(null)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**
OK, this is getting even more weird. Following @DavidMear to the letter I updated it so the children were added in the onChildXComplete function and suddenly it breaks MUCH less frequently. It does still break very occasionally though:

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var child1Factory:Object;
    private var child1Loaded:Boolean = false;
    private var child2Factory:Object;
    private var child2Loaded:Boolean = false;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        Security.allowDomain("*")
        if (stage) loadChildren();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);
    }

    private function loadChildren(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);

        child1Loaded = false
        child2Loaded = false

        var child1Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child1Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild1Complete)
        child1Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child1Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))

        var child2Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child2Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild2Complete)
        child2Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child2Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))


    }

    private function onChild1Complete(e:Event):void {
        child1Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child1Loaded = true
        var child1:MovieClip = child1Factory.getChild1()
        addChild(child1)
        if (child2Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }   

    }

    private function onChild2Complete(e:Event):void {
        child2Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child2Loaded = true
        var child2:MovieClip = child2Factory.getChild2()
        addChild(child2)
        if (child1Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }

    }

    private function onLoadComplete():void {
        loadChildren(null)
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3**

This code throws the error at much the same frequency as the origional and the stack trace points towards one of the timer handlers. It also throws the error if there are no timers with the stack trace pointing towards onLoadComplete... i.e. the test function has already run successfully once in the onChildXComplete function before it throws the error. Now I'm **REALLY** confused.

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{
    private var child1Factory:Object;
    private var child1Loaded:Boolean = false;
    private var child2Factory:Object;
    private var child2Loaded:Boolean = false;

    public function Main():void 
    {
        Security.allowDomain("*")
        if (stage) loadChildren();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);
    }

    private function loadChildren(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, loadChildren);

        child1Loaded = false
        child2Loaded = false

        var child1Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child1Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild1Complete)
        child1Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child1Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))

        var child2Loader:Loader = new Loader()
        child2Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChild2Complete)
        child2Loader.load(new URLRequest("http://mywebsite.com/assets/load_test/Child2Factory.swf?" + Math.random()), new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain)))


    }

    private function onChild1Complete(e:Event):void {
        child1Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child1Loaded = true
        var child1:MovieClip = child1Factory.getChild1()
        addChild(child1)
        if (child2Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }   

    }

    private function onChild2Complete(e:Event):void {
        child2Factory = e.currentTarget.content
        child2Loaded = true
        var child2:MovieClip = child2Factory.getChild2()
        addChild(child2)
        if (child1Loaded) {
            onLoadComplete()
        }

    }

    private function onLoadComplete():void {

        var timer1:Timer = new Timer(500, 1) 
        timer1.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
            var child1:MovieClip = child1Factory.getChild1()
            addChild(child1)
        })
        timer1.start()

        var timer2:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1) 
        timer2.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
            var child2:MovieClip = child2Factory.getChild2()
            addChild(child2)
            loadChildren(null)
        })
        timer2.start()          

    }

}
```

Comment: The fact that it happens intermittently and only when loading across a network makes me suspect it's to do with the timing of when the test is run. It might be possible that `Child1` is added to the stage before the swf is fully loaded, so does running the test on `onChild1Complete` make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidMear. I've updated the question with the full code of the loader class. Child1 should not be added to the stage before onChild1Complete has been called. I have tried explicity splitting out the test but unfortunately no joy. I quite agree with your assesment though. It does seem like it's not fully loaded. Is there another event I could listen for or anything?

Comment: Hi @DavidMear. Can you have a look at my second update above. It's getting more and more strange. Would you expect it to behave differently?

Comment: I've now combined the origional with update 2 so child1/child2 is being added on onChild1Complete/onChild2Complete and then they are both being added again onLoadComplete. The error occurs and the stack trace points to the **onLoadComplete** function. **Very strange because to me it means it's already worked fine once when onChildXComplete was called so it must have been loaded correctly**. I'm so confused. Do you guys think I should file a bug report with Adobe?

Comment: Wow, update 2 seemed encouraging, but update 3 has me stumped. I replicated your latest set up myself and I can confirm I see the error from the timers once every 5 or so tries when loading from a server. It probably is worth filing a bug report with a zip of your files to test with. I'll fiddle a bit more, but hopefully someone else might have an idea.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMear. Glad it's not something specific to my setup.

Comment: Here's something, though I still can't suggest a fix. Tracing out the currentFrame when each load completes, the error only occurs when the loads complete on *different frames*, and only in the swf which loaded first. Alternatively, loading the swfs one after the other I can get the error every time from the timer test. It seems as if the second swf being added to the stage is what breaks things in the first.

Comment: Very interesting David. I'm going to file a bug once I've finished on a (pretty long) work around and I'll make sure to include that. It sounds like it might be useful if they ever come to fix it :).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the findChildrenOfType method is not quite right to be called recursively, as you are resetting the toReturn array on each call. Perhaps something like this might work better?

```
function findChildrenOfType(type:Class, container:DisplayObjectContainer, toReturn:Array = null ):Array {
    if(!toReturn) toReturn = [];
    for (var childIndex:int = 0; childIndex < container.numChildren; childIndex++) {
        var child:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(childIndex)
        if (child is type) {
            toReturn.push(child);
        } else if (child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
            findChildrenOfType( type, child as DisplayObjectContainer, toReturn );
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spending the time looking over this @Dezza. I'm pretty certain the origional function works fine. Like I said it only breaks occasionally. Your function would also work from the looks of it and both do the same thing. In my function the array doesn't need to be preserved. It's a different array every time the function is called. The resultant arrays are concatenated.

Comment: The Child classes work perfectly in isolation or if only 1 of them is loaded or if they are loaded off the same computer. They also work a lot of the time even if both are loaded from another computer. It's an incosistant error I'm getting so I'm pretty certain there isn't anything wrong with the logic itself.